# jQuery dynamically append table rows without flickering

Tags: jquery

I have a page that every 5 seconds fetch new data from the server with jQuery ajax and append it to a table. 

Everything is working fine except from one annoying issue.every append action causing the table to flickers.

I am looking for a way to smooth things a bit, and make this action more "eye friendly" for the user.

HTML:

```
  <table id="myTable">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>COL A</th>
       <th>COL B</th>
       <th>COL C</th>                                    
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>

     </tbody>
    </table>
```

jQuery:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('#myTable tbody').empty();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/MySite/WebMethods/AjaxTestMethods.aspx/GetActivityTable",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    var d = data.d;
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr><td>' + d[i].DATA1 + '</td><td>' + d[i].DATA2 +'</td><td>' + d[i].DATA3 + '</td><tr>'); 
     }
    }
  });
 }, 5000);
```

Comment: Maybe you can use loading bar? :)With a fadeInt effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are abundant articles out there on how to write idiomatic, fast jQuery code.  Please read up.  Here is one that briefly covers this issue:

http://www.slideshare.net/AddyOsmani/jquery-proven-performance-tips-tricks

For this particular problem, you need to do 2 things:

1. cache your tbody lookup
2. combine your appends

Probably what you meant to do here is this:

```
var rows = "";
for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    rows += '<tr><td>' + d[i].DATA1 + '</td><td>' + d[i].DATA2 +'</td><td>' + d[i].DATA3 + '</td><tr>'; 
}

$('#myTable tbody').append(rows);
```

Detach can also be helpful, but given that you have the data all at once I don't expect it will help much.  But you might try that as well if it doesn't help enough.

PS:  Don't forget to escape your Ajax data for HTML entities.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are emptying the table. You should look only for new rows. Perhaps you can pass an "id" in your request, and only get what has been added after it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider usinga 'loading...' image or message. [see this one](http://www.linein.org/blog/2010/05/12/jquery-ajax-loading-display-images-or-text-until-script-is-finished-part-2/) That will make it more "eye friendly"